# Killing vector fields on Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A vector field $X$ is a Killing field if the Lie derivative with respect to $X$ of the metric $g$ vanishes.

But if we're on an Euclidean space the metric tensor is constant, so it's Lie derivative on every vector field should vanish. If I work on local coordinates instead I find that only source-free vector fields are Killing.

Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The Lie derivative of a constant tensor field is not the zero tensor.

Answer (score 3):

The Euclidean metric *in standard Euclidean coordinates* is constant, but this does not mean it is ``Lie constant'' for every vector field $X$. Indeed, using the Leibniz rule for the Lie derivative of tensors, we get
$$
X(g(Y, Z)) = (L_X g)(Y, Z) + g([X, Y], Z) + g(Y, [X, Z]).
$$
If we let $Y = \partial_i$ and $Z = \partial_j$ be standard coordinate vector fields, then this becomes
$$
Xg_{ij} = (L_X g)_{ij} + g([X, \partial_i], \partial_j) + g(\partial_i, [X, \partial_j]).
$$
If $L_Xg = 0$ then this gives us that $g([X, \partial_i], \partial_j) + g(\partial_i, [X, \partial_j]) = Xg_{ij}$. In the case of the standard Euclidean metric in standard coordinates, we have $g_{ij} = 0$ and thus the right hand side vanishes. At this point we use that the Lie bracket  in coordinates is
$$
[X, Y] = (X^k\partial_k Y^\ell - Y^k \partial_k X^\ell)\partial_\ell
$$
so
$$
[X, \partial_i] = -\delta_i^k \partial_k X^\ell \partial_\ell = -\partial_i X^\ell \partial_\ell, \ \ \ \ [X, \partial_j] = -\partial_j X^\ell \partial_\ell.
$$
Thus our equation above for $L_X g = 0$ becomes
$$
\partial_i X^\ell g_{\ell j} + \partial_j X^\ell g_{\ell i} = 0.
$$
But we know the metric components are $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, so this is saying that
$$
\partial_i X^j + \partial_j X^i = 0,
$$
which is the condition $X$ must satisfy to be a Killing field. Indeed, Killing's equation in this case reads exactly this. Note that setting $i = j$ and summing gives $\text{div}X = 0$.

Comment: Ok I understood Leibniz and calculations, but maybe I'm missing a deeper understanding of what does the Lie derivative actually do when applied to a tensor field. "The Euclidean metric in standard Euclidean coordinates is constant, but this does not mean it is ``Lie constant'' for every vector field X". Could you explain this in a more geometrical or intuitive way? Thank you.

Comment: I think the first thing to think about is that the phrase "the Euclidean metric is constant" does not really make any sense. It is only constant in a certain preferred set of coordinates (standard Cartesian/Euclidean coordinates). If you express the metric in polar coordinates, it is not constant in these coordinates. Thus any coincidental constancy in a specific set of coordinates is *not* a geometric property, whereas the Lie derivative of $g$, being a tensor, is coordinate independent.